# JavaScript array weirdness?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I think this is just me not understanding part of how JavaScript works. Let's say I have an array, call it `arr1`, with 6 ints in it,  `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`. If I make a new array:

```
var arr2 = arr1
```

(for the purpose of maintaining an unchanged copy of `arr1`), when I change `arr1` the changes are reflected in `arr2`.

Basically, I am manipulating `arr1`. For testing purposes I wanted to have an unchanged copy of `arr1` so that when I'm done I can console.log them both out on my web page and see the differences in them. But again, when I make changes in `arr1`, that change is reflected in `arr2`.

Can anyone explain why this happens and maybe a way around it? I'm more interested in why this happens than how to fix it.

One approach is to make `arr2` a separate array, and use a for loop to populate it with `arr1`'s data

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) arr2[i] = arr1[i]
```

but, if the array was huge, that might be expensive. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As a side note, this behavior is called cloning.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you assign non-primitives (such as arrays), **you're not making a copy.** You're creating another reference to the same array.

If you want to *copy* an array:

```
var arr2 = arr1.slice();
// or
var arr2 = arr1.concat();
```

More reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: @Kolink not even a second. I see `2012-11-21 18:44:50Z` for both our answers. `:)`

Comment: Thanks both of you for the quickest answers.

Answer (score 3):

Objects are passed by reference, not by value.

To create a copy of the array, try:

```
var arr2 = arr1.slice(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is dealing with arrays by reference, so your `arr1` and `arr2` are actually pointing at the same array.

What you probably want to do is clone the array, which you can do with `slice`

```
var arr2 = arr1.slice(0);
```